# Ajax.BeginForm doesn't submit form values

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, ajax.beginform

I want to use Ajax.BeginForm on my ASP.NET MVC project and below is the code on a .cshtml file

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("ActionName", "ControllerName", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", UpdateTargetId = "DivName" }))
{
    <input type="hidden" name="posted" id="posted" value="5" />
    <input type="submit" id="sBtn" value="Submit" />
}
```

And my action is below but I could not get the posted param in the action. Why?

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ActionName(string posted)
{ 

   //posted is null why?
    ....
 }
```

I have added

```
<add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
```

to web.config

and

```
"~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js"
```

to bundle

If I use Html.BeginForm instead of Ajax.BeginForm on a .cshtml everything works fine.

Answer (score 1):

with Ajax.BeginForm, in your controller you need to Request["the name of your input"] as follows :

```
public ActionResult ActionName()
{ 
   string Posted = Request["posted"];

    //Some more code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try ensuring that the method you are posting to is decorated with the [`[HttpPost]`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.httppostattribute(v=vs.118).aspx) attribute, which will ensure that it can receive `POST` requests :

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ActionName(string posted)
{ 

}
```

Besides that your code appears like it should work just as expected. The following example should demonstrate both scenarios in action :

**HomeController.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace PostingExample
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index(string posted, bool isAjax = false)
        {
            return Content(String.Format("{0} was posted. {1}",posted, isAjax ? "(via AJAX)" : ""));
        }
    }
}
```

**Index.cshtml**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Post Testing</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>Normal Form</h2>
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home"))
    {
        <input type="hidden" name="posted" id="posted" value="5" />
        <input type="submit" id="sBtn" value="Submit" />
    }
    <h2>AJAX Form</h2>
    @using (Ajax.BeginForm("Index", "Home", new AjaxOptions() { HttpMethod = "Post", UpdateTargetId = "DivName" }))
    {
        <input type="hidden" name="posted" id="posted" value="5" />
        <input type='submit'>
    }

    <!-- jQuery and related scripts -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
    <script src='http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/mvc/5.2.3/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js' />
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Html.BeginForm is working but Ajax.BeginForm is not working

Comment: I tried using [an example that is structured as similar as possible to your own](https://gist.github.com/Rionmonster/2a62521a07335bb56d20dc897ef0ba94) and it works as expected. Can you try ensuring that all of the information is the same as the provided example?

Comment: You may want to ensure that your `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js` file is being properly loaded and there aren't any 404 errors within the Developer Tools (F12) in your browser pertaining to it.

Comment: You can [see an example here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/jMgMhc) that should demonstrated both of them in action.